$k$-subset with minimal Hausdorff distance to the whole set
Let $(\mathcal{M}, d)$ be a metric space. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $[\mathcal{M}]^k$ be the set of $k$-subsets of $\mathcal{M}$. Consider the following problem:
$$ \operatorname*{argmin}_{\mathcal{S} \subseteq [\mathcal{M}]^k} d_\text{Hausdorff}(\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{M}) = \operatorname*{argmin}_{\mathcal{S} \subseteq [\mathcal{M}]^k} \sup_{x \in \mathcal{M}} \inf_{y \in \mathcal{S}} d(x, y) $$
This is the problem of finding a $k$-subset of $\mathcal{M}$ that is as close as possible to $\mathcal{M}$, in the sense of Hausdorff distance.
It can be seen as a generalization of the facility location problem.
Question: Does this general problem have a standard name in the literature? Are there any good references for it?
Consider the special case where $\mathcal{M} = [0, 1]^n$ is the unit $n$-cube, and $d$ is the Euclidean metric.
Question: What are the best-known constructions for general $n$ and $k$, in the sense of attaining low distance?

This can be thought of as a type of covering problem, where the goal is to cover $\mathcal{M}$ with $k$ circles of radius as small as possible.
It is similar to the disk covering problem with a unit square (or other $\mathcal{M}$) instead of unit disk.
The following paper studies the problem of computing such an optimal cover:

Optimal covering points and curves. Justin Tzou and Brian Wetton. AIMS Mathematics 4.6 (2019): 1796-1804.


We consider the optimal covering of the unit square by N circles. By optimal, we mean the covering that can be done with N circles of minimum radius. Equivalently, we study the problem of the optimal placement of N points such that the maximum over all locations in the square of the distance of the location to the set of points is minimized.


We consider in this work the problem of optimally distributing points inside a domain so that, when the Euclidean distance to the nearest design point is computed for all locations on the domain, the maximum of these distances is minimized.

A partial description of the algorithm is as follows:

The algorithm has two stages with iterations at each stage. We call the $N$ points $P_j$ to be placed design points. At each iteration of the first stage, the point $Q$ in the domain that is farthest away from its nearest design points is found. Then, design points nearest to $Q$ are moved towards it. In the second stage, an optimization problem is solved with Newton iterations that can find design points to machine precision.


We define $\delta$ as the largest of the distances computed from every point in the domain to the nearest design point(s). [...] To compute $\delta$ for a particular arrangement of design points, we admit the following locations in the domain as candidates for being one of the points $Q_i$: the four corners, centres of circles situated on the domain boundary passing through two design points, and centres of circles situated strictly inside the domain passing through three design points. The centres of the circles with radii equal to the largest of all the radii are taken as points $Q_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, M$. Of course, to be an actual candidate, no design points can be strictly inside the circle. It is fairly easy to see that this finite set of possible $Q$ does produce the largest distance $\delta$ in the square to the set of design points.

